# Sum of array elements returns NaN

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
var Arr = [-1,3,-4,5,1,-6,2,1];

function solution ( A ) {
  var sum;
  var len = A.length;
  for ( var key in A ) {
    sum += +(parseInt(A[key]));
  }
  return sum;
}

solution( Arr );
```

and it returns NaN. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Besides initializing `sum` to 0, you can remove `parseInt`, assuming the array elements will always be numeric.  Also, avoid using `in` when accessing array elements, in case `Array.prototype` has been extended.  A `for` loop would be best in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working version of your code

```
function solution ( A ) {
  var sum = 0;
  var len = A.length;
  for ( key in A ) {
    sum += parseInt(A[key], 10);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

You should initialize `sum`  also your `+(parseInt(A[key]))`  has the same effect as `parseInt(A[key])`

Comment: use radix 10 for parseInt

Comment: It's weird that I tried it in the first instance and it didn't work. So initialization was the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You never initialize `sum`, so it starts `undefined`.

`undefined` + number = `NaN`

Answer (score 3):

`undefined` + "any number" is *always*  `NaN`.

Declare `sum` with a starting value of `0`. (aka: initialize it)

```
var sum = 0;
```

Also, it's a good idea to use a radix in [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
parseInt(A[key], 10)
```

This makes sure `parseInt` always tries to interpret `A[key]` as a decimal number.